# Which service account is suitable?

Tags: windows, security, service, privileges

I have developed a .NET Windows Service (in VS2010) that needs to:

- Access shared folders (read/write) on machines on the local network
- Write to HKLM/SOFTWARE part of the registry
- Write files and create folders in all parts of the local file system (ex. in root of C:)
- Download files from the web (using http)

My service must do well with all Windows (PC) operating systems, starting from Windows XP SP3 and onwards.

**Problem: Which service account should I choose for my service?**

Normally, I would use either “*LocalService*” or “*NetworkService*”, but none of those grants all needed privileges by themselves.

Should I use the “*LocalSystem*” account then? Or, should I create a complete separate account for my service's use only (this should then be done automatically during installation)?

For now I use the “*NetworkService*” account and just adds it to the adimistrators group during installation, which works fine. But I think this approach ruins the whole idea about limited service accounts and thus poses a security risk - don’t you agree?

Comment: Just make a domain user account, rather than escalate every single NetworkService based service to administrator. I'm sure the sysadmins installing your product on terminal servers just love you. Deny the account log on via console and grant log on as a service. Add it to the local administrators group on the PC.

Comment: Not all machines that run my service belong to a domain (some machines are completely stand-alones). Further, creating and configuring a separate service account must be doable from code during installation, since my customers will have no idea how to accomplish this manually (and they have no IT department around to ask). Is creating a separate service account still doable (and managable) this way? Are there strong arguments against just using the LocalSystem account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `LOCALSYSTEM`. This has far too much power and all best practice tells you not to use it.

In my view you should be creating a local user with appropriate rights as part of your installation. This is a fairly common practice for server/database products.

Comment: Ok. I take it that creating a new local user account is the only clean solution to my problem. However, I have no clue on how to do this from code, so this will most likely be my my next question unless I can google something useful up. Thank you all very much for this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to separate out your requirements.

You mention needing access to shares on other computers, but then you also mention that the machines this service will be installed on won't necessarily be part of the domain.

Have the service execute under a user account that grants you the appropriate LOCAL permissions.  Then have some type of alternative user account with access to the appropriate shares that your service knows about and impersonates when needed.

Now, with regard to writing and creating files in the ROOT, that's going to be *interesting*.  Your service will need full administrative permissions in order to do this on a Windows 7 box if UAC is turned on.  Which, it would probably be safe to assume is on machines you don't directly control.  Either eliminate this requirement or you'll have to live with the idea that your service is a security risk.

Comment: All good stuff here but note that UAC does not apply to session 0 and hence to services. Since that session has no desktop you can't very well show the UAC dialog. Users with admin rights always run with a full token in session 0.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the security risk regarding full administrative permissions in order to write to the root of C: (actually I don't need to write files to the root, but to create folders from the root and write files into them, but I guess the security issues are the same). The need for writing files in those locations come from earlier versions of my service, when only Windows XP was around - and I need to be compatible with those versions.